# Computing the probability density of wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

Suppose I am given a Hamiltonian operator $\hat{H}$ that satisfies the time-independent Schrödinger equation $$\hat{H} \psi = E\psi$$ I can compute energy eigenvalues and their associated eigenvectors. What is the procedure for calculating the probability density the system will collapse into a particular eigenstate? I am guessing to compute the probability I will need a normalization condition for the wave function, but that's about all I understand. What is the procedure for calculating the probability density? I am unsure how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "probability density of the eigenvectors"? The probability density is a property of a (ensemble of) states, not of the Hamiltonian or its eigenvectors.

Comment: Well the eigenvectors in this case are the stationary states of the Hamiltonian are they not? If not, how would I compute the wavefunctions seeing as I don't have any explicit ones - just the Hamiltonian itself.

Comment: You compute the wavefunction the same as always - take the inner product of the states with the position eigenstates: $\psi(x) := \langle x \vert \psi \rangle$. That's got nothing to do with the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Then I'm a little confused. What are my states then if not the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian (which is the only thing I am given). Would I not in this case take the inner product of x with my eigenvector(s)? I am doing this computationally because the Hamiltonian is a 30x30 matrix, which may be what is confusing me a bit. Thanks!

Comment: You...don't actually have "wavefunctions" if your space is not infinite, i.e. if you don't have the operators $x$ and $p$ acting on it.

Comment: Well that's just really confusing. I'm told to find wavefunctions for the given Hamiltonian for a discrete lattice after computing the eigenvalues. I'm guessing what was meant was to find the eigenstates/vectors, which I have done, but that still leaves me nowhere regarding then computing their probability density.

Comment: Finding the probability density of the eigenstates isn't really something that makes sense, so it's no wonder you don't know how to do it. Are you sure that's what you have to do?

Comment: The only thing that might make sense is finding the equilibrium state(s) for the given Hamiltonian (at a given temperature) which is done via Gibbs' measures/the canonical ensemble. Otherwise, the question of states is separate from a given Hamiltonian...